# Recommendations for travel insurance which covers unattended stolen goods

Tags: insurance, interrail, travel-insurance-claim

I am an Australian citizen going interrailing in Serbia, Albania, Italy and Spain in a few days time.

I need to bring my laptop to be able to work and I feel very scared that it will be stolen, lost, or damaged somehow.

How should I go about covering myself for the following cases:

- My laptop is stolen while left unattended somewhere
- I accidentally leave my laptop somewhere and lose it
- My laptop gets damaged by water

Is there a good insurance provider that covers these types of things that anyone can recommend? I will only need the insurance for two months.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I hope that you are aware that you can't get Interrail as an Australian, and that a Pass is not good value for those countries anyway...

Comment: Which "somewheres" do you want to be covered in your first bullet point? There's a big difference between "I left my laptop unattended in my hotel room and it was stolen." and "I left my laptop unattended in a coffee shop and it was stolen."

Comment: @KristvanBesien wow I didn't know that! Thanks so much for alerting me! I just looked it up and it says I can buy a Eurail pass. Is there a better value option? I want to go from Serbia > Albania > Greece > Italy (ferry) > Spain

Comment: @AnthonyGrist ideally I'd be looking for something that covers everything all the way to "I left my laptop unattended in a coffee shop and it was stolen." Is that too optimistic? Do you know of any companies that offer similar policies?

Comment: Any policy will require a "duty of care" by the policy holder, or maybe charge you more than the maximum value you can claim.

Comment: You need to visit the Man in Seat 61 here https://www.seat61.com/how-to-use-a-eurail-pass.htm to read a detailed account of the pluses and minuses of rail passes over just buying point to point tickets.

Comment: @John: Albania has no rail service to speak of. Greece and Serbia don't have a lot either. You will be using busses there mostly. Spain and Italy require you to reserve seats in advance on long distance trains. Go to the seat61 site and start studying.

Comment: Great, thanks so much for all this info guys. I really appreciate it.

Comment: In relation to the travel insurance question, does anyone have any particular companies that they'd recommend?

Comment: The best way to protect your laptop is to *tether* it to you. Then you can't leave it at a cafe table or elsewhere accidentally, and it can't be taken by "snatch and grab".

Comment: @John It's not allowed on this site to give recommendations for specific services.

Comment: For bags on train luggage racks a cheap bike lock will deal with the common form of theft - grabbing an attractive bag and getting off just before the doors close.  Tuck the lock out of sight under the bag, locking it to the rack.  Not exactly what you're asking for, but deals with one threat, and can be useful in other situations

Comment: Product recommendations are off-topic across all of StackExchange, except for the hardware-reco and software-reco "dungeons", which only deal in computer stuff and aren't very well answered.

Comment: I suggest backup of your data by some means, thus limiting the risk to the cost of buying a new laptop and restoring the previous environment.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a good insurance provider that covers these types of things

Unlikely. Almost all insurances will have an exclusion clause for "negligence" which the insurance will try to interpret extremely broadly and wouldn't cover any of your use cases.

A few things to consider instead

1. The risk is much lower than you probably think. I've travelled 100s of times and my loss rate is extremely low. I have on occasion left an item behind but in almost all cases I was able to recover it or it was returned to me. Most people are nice !
2. Use a cheap laptop for travel. If you just need maps, email, office etc, a cheap chrome book can do just fine. If that's gone, just buy another one. In general: don't take your most valuable possession when you are travelling.

Comment: You must be very lucky then. I live in Italy, and I wouldn't count on finding my laptop ever again if I left it unattended in a public place. Not even for a few minutes. Telling them that it's safe to leave a computer unattended because chances are nobody is going to steal it is a huge way to mislead them into losing it.

Comment: @Mr_Bober it depends on the item.  You need to be more careful with high value/risk stuff, but if that means you neglect the less valuable stuff you should get away with it - most of the time

Comment: @Mr_Bober in a bus station in another country I could not *give away* a book I had finished with. Nobody would have it, even reacting as if I was trying to hit on them for something. However when I left it on an empty seat someone took it within seconds.

Comment: @Mr_Bober: I've travelled extensively in Italy and my brother in law still lives there.  No incidents. The general rule: don't do anything stupid. And yes, leaving your laptop on a park bench qualifies as stupid, so I try to avoid it.

Comment: @Hilmar Calling OP stupid doesn't help your point. He clearly stated he's worried about his laptop being stolen if left unattended. I guess he's used to do so in his hometown, without consequence. Not sure why you picked a park bench as an example, seems odd, but in general no place is safe to leave a laptop. It being on your train seat while going to the bathroom, or on your table while you order something at a bar, or in the reception of your hotel while you talk to the receptionist. I've had a worthless old laptop stolen from a university class, where you had to show ID to get in.

Comment: @WeatherVane I would assume it's because people thought you were trying to scam or trick them somehow. There's lots of scams going around that involve getting "a free item", usually involving pickpocketing while you're distracted.

Comment: @ChrisH-UK Agreed, it depends on the item. But OP is talking about his laptop, which even if it's an old model is generally a "high value / risk" item when it comes to theft.

Comment: @Mr_Bober: Sorry, I wasn't intending to call the OP stupid. My point here is "behave smart when you travel". Don't go into dark alleys alone at night, don't flaunt large wads of cash in public, be culturally aware of what might be taken as an insult, etc.  And "Don't leave stuff lying around more than you have to," falls into that category for me.

Answer (score 2):

Exact coverage of any given insurance is going to depend on the exact policy terms.

In general a policy is not going to give carte blanch coverage. If you put your laptop down on a park bench and wander away for a few hours, no policy will cover that. On the other hand if you leave your laptop in a locked hotel room and somebody breaks open the lock and steals it you are probably covered. Ask your broker.

If you are actually scared about the idea of your laptop being stolen I would not take it with you. Theft of your personal belongings on a trip like this isn't that common, but it's something you should take into consideration. Maybe you could buy a cheaper laptop for the trip and take that.

Answer (score 1):

Insurance is designed to cover unexpected situations beyond the control of the ensured. So coverage for an unattended laptop in an unsecured location is extremely unlikely. They can cover an laptop that is in a secured location, even if unattended. For example, if you rent a locker to place you valuables, then even if the locker-rental service company waives responsibility for lost or stolen items, your own insurance could cover such situation.

Water damage will be covered by many insurance, when not caused by negligence. If something leaks over or the room floods, then that *could* be covered. Each insurance has it's own terms that you must examine closely.

You may already be covered those cases, excluding negligence. If you have home insurance, then they often insure a percentage of the insured value outside of the home. Otherwise, you have to shop around and ask questions from various insurance companies available to you.